# How can I find out the version of a driver in the Windows Update dialog?

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-update

I find it annoying that in the Windows Update dialog, when there is a driver listed as available, you can't get more details other than a generic name for the driver. In the right-hand panel, there is a link for "More information", but clicking it always takes me to the useless page: http://winqual.microsoft.com/help/default.htm#winqual_requirements.htm.

I generally get the latest drivers for my system from the system assembler (e.g. Lenovo) or the manufacturer of the particular hardware for which I'm getting the driver, but sometimes I'd like to compare what is available from these sources with what is shown in Windows Update. Yes, I know that these WHQL drivers are behind usually, but it wouldn't hurt to find out the specifics.

This has been bugging me for some time - hopefully someone knows the answer.

Comment: Another reason Not to use WU for drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for your updated driver in the Microsoft Update Catalog:

http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/home.aspx

By looking at the release date and driver id, you can usually figure out what version is updated exactly.

I have found some updates that were not listed in the catalog however. The windows update log file, which is located in "%WINDIR%/windowsupdate.log", can tell you a lot more and provide you with the exact download link from which you can download the update (usually a cab file) and then see all the contents within that update.

Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: Starting in Windows 8.1 and continuing in Windows 10, Windows Update client uses Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) to generate diagnostic logs.

Run the `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` PowerShell command to convert ETW traces into a readable WindowsUpdate.log.

For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518345

Comment: Regarding the statement: "You can search for your updated driver in the Microsoft Update Catalog", note that the Microsoft Update Catalog ís searchable by the `updateid` guid, although it is not mentioned explicidly. So if you don't find the update by its updateid in the Microsoft Update Catalog, it might be superseded or a hotfix that is not listed.